# maven post-remove tries to remove mapped files

Tags: rpm-maven-plugin

I'm using maven to create an rpm that I can use to install my app.

In my of my mappings I specify a directory that contains files that are needed for the post-install step:

```
            <mappings>
                <mapping>
                    <directory>${rpm.info.install_dir}</directory>
                    <filemode>700</filemode>
                    <sources>
                        <source>
                            <location>src/main/resources/install</location>
                        </source>
                    </sources>
                </mapping>
            </mappings>
```

In my post-install step I use those files and in the end of the step I delete the directory. As a result, in the post-remove step I'm getting multiple errors that all the files in the directory `${rpm.info.install_dir}` don't exist:

```
Remove  1 Package

Installed size: 46 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Erasing    : my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.noarch                                                                                                                                                        1/1
warning: file /data/install/file1.conf: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /data/install/file2.conf: remove failed: No such file or directory
warning: file /data/install/dir1/file1.service: remove failed: No such file or directory
```

I guess that rpm will try to remove all files mentioned in spec file (%files) in the post-remove step. Is there any way to avoid this action? I do want to remove the install directory after the post-install step and not wait with it until customer decides to delete the rpm.